# VSCode executes cd command before my code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, command-prompt

[image]

cmd is my default Terminal, even though in the settings I have written such:

```
  "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\Sysnative\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
```

When I was using PowerShell, it didn't run such command. I am coding in pure Python 3.6, no import statements.

Answer (score 0):

VS Code will `cd` into the directory you specified for the `"cwd":` attribute in `launch.json`. This is a feature that is meant to preserve the location that VS Code runs the launch configuration from.

Comment: But the cmd already opens in that directory, so the cd command has no effect

Comment: Right, but say you specified a different path for `"cwd"`... Then it would cd into that, (different) directory.

Comment: Well, no, here is my cwd setting `"terminal.integrated.cwd": "",`

Comment: No, not the `"terminal.integrated.cwd": "",`, the literal `"cwd"` setting in the `launch.json` file

Comment: Where can i find the file sorry?

Comment: That is beside the point. As long as it works, it is fine to keep the `"cwd"` as is. In fact, removing it is not recommended, as it is required.

Comment: well ok but I do not think I changed anything on launch.json since I do not even know where to find it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155164/discussion-between-ifconfig-and-dreamit).